# LaTeX Package "changes" - Remove Anonymous Author

Tags: pdftex, changes

With the "changes" package, is it possible to either remove or rename the "anonymous author" which is added automatically by the package?

When using

```
\definechangesauthor[name={My Name}, color=orange]{me}
\listofchanges[style=summary, title={Corrections Summary}]
```

I see two authors listed, one "me (My Name)", as added by the `definechangesauthor` command, and a second "Anonymous" as shown below:

```
Author:  anonymous 
No changes.
 
Author:  me (My Name) 
Added   . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  4
Deleted   . . . . . . . . . . . . .  2
Replaced  . . . . . . . . . . . .  7
Highlighted   . . . . . . . . .  0
Commented  . . . . . . . . .  0
```

I would either like to be able to remove the block for "anonymous" which is empty, or better still be able to rename "Anonymous" to my name and avoid having to use `\definechangesauthor` altogether.

However I can't see anything in the documentation for the package to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the macro `\changesanonymousname`. If you use the `babel` package then you need to put the redefinition *after* `\begin{document}` because the `changes` package tells `babel` to set the predefined name in the current language during `\begin{document}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}
\def\changesanonymousname{Tom Carpenter}
abc
\added{def}
\deleted{klm}
xyz

\listofchanges[style=summary, title={Corrections Summary}]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's where I went wrong. I had tried redefining `\changesanonymousname`, but it seemed to do nothing - I'd put it in the premable not after `\begin{document}`. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**First solution.** Changing the definition of `\changesanonymousname`. Note that there is no superscriot "Id" as there is only one author here (the anonymous renamed Bob):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
 \def\changesanonymousname{Bob}
\begin{document}
  Hello world \added{Text added}
    \listofchanges[style=summary, title={Corrections Summary}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to change the default color to orange:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defaultcolor=orange]{changes}
 \def\changesanonymousname{Bob}
  \def\changesauthorname{\color{orange}Author}
\begin{document}
  Hello world\added{Text added by Bob}
    \listofchanges[style=summary, title={Corrections Summary}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Second solution.** An attempt to "delete" the anonymous author. The anonymous is still there but he is "invisible" until a command without `id` option is entered (for example `\added{text added}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
  \definechangesauthor[name={My Name}, color=orange]{me}

\usepackage{xpatch}
  \makeatletter
    \xpatchcmd{\listofchanges}{\changesauthorname: \changesanonymousname}{}{}{}
    \xpatchcmd{\listofchanges}{\parbox{\Changes@summary@width}{\changesnochanges}\\[1ex]}{}{}
  \makeatletter

\begin{document} 
  Hello world\added[id=me]{Text added by me}
    \listofchanges[style=summary, title={Corrections Summary}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I opened an issue for this problem:

https://gitlab.com/ekleinod/changes/-/issues/107

As I wrote there:

To achieve this as fast as possible, just use:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\def\changesanonymousname{your name}}
```

This should work in the preamble as well.

But this only affects the summary list of changes.

I think, when using `\usepackage[authormarkuptext=name]{changes}` the name "Anonymous" should appear, too. At the moment, the name is empty for the anonymous author as well.

*Update 2021-07-07:*

The issue is closed, from v4.2.0 on there is a command

`\setanonymousname`

which sets the name of the anonymous author to a name of your choice.

v4.2.0 was uploaded to CTAN on 2021-07-07, it normally should be in the distros in 2-5 days.